# Image picker delegate error: cannot assign value of type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement this framework from Github: 
https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker

Then I created an `IBAction` in my view controller as described in the `Description`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationBarDelegate {

@IBAction func addMemory(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let imagePickerController = ImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self //Error here
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

> Error: Cannot assign value of type 'MemoriesTable' to type
>   'ImagePickerDelegate?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be implementing `ImagePickerDelegate` as well, because delegate is of type `ImagePickerDelegate`. Change as follow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationBarDelegate, ImagePickerDelegate {
```

Make sure you implement protocol methods.

**EDIT 1**

You need to implement following methods of `ImagePickerDelegate`

```
public protocol ImagePickerDelegate: class {

   func wrapperDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])
   func doneButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage])
   func cancelButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController)
}
```

Comment: Great! It works. But why don't I have to implement `tableViewController.delegate = self` ?

Comment: You might have done that in storyboard or xib itself while adding tableview. If you have not done that in storyboard then you have to set delegate and datasource in code, and implement the necessary protocol methods.

Comment: I did as you said, but now there's a new error: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ImagePickerDelegate'

Answer (score 2):

Revisit my own question 10 months later.

Simply change this line:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationBarDelegate
```

to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationBarDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

will make it work.

Comment: This should be the updated answer. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

if you are implement the `ImagePickerController` then you need to add the following delegate   **UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** on your class

at the same time you need to implement the following delegate methods also

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = pickedImage
}

dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
} 




func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)    {
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive had similar issue. I realized picker.delegate = self was missing. Adding it fixed the issue

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker:UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        print(editedImage.size)
    }



    else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]  as? UIImage{
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        print(originalImage.size)

    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker{
        Profileimg.image = selectedImage

    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```